# Bad Gateway 502 on Openshift NodeJS app when uploading a file

Tags: angularjs, node.js, response, openshift, gateway

i've got an Application based on NodeJS and AngularJS and pushed it to openshift. But everytime i try to upload something, i get the following error:

```
POST http://www.domain.de/api/upload/file 502 (Bad Gateway)
```

Angular sends the data like this:

```
$scope.newFile = function() {
    $scope.id = $scope.group._id;
    var fd = new FormData();
    var file = $scope.files[0];
    fd.append('file', file);
    if (file.type!="application/pdf"){
        mvNotifier.error("Nur PDF Dateien sind akzeptiert.");
        return;
    }       
    $http.post('/api/upload/file', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers:{'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(d) {
        var data = {
            name: file.name,
            description: $scope.descriptionfile
        }
        mvNotifier.notify("Bis hier hin klappt alles");
        console.log("sucess on uploading ");

        mvFactory.POST(data, mvGroup, {_place:"file", _id:$scope.id}).then(function(data) {
            $scope.newfile=false;
            $scope.group.files.push({name:file.name, description:$scope.descriptionfile});
            mvNotifier.notify("Datei hochgeladen");
        }, function(reason) {
            mvNotifier.error("reason");
        })
    })
    .error(function(data,status,header) {
        mvNotifier.error("Upload hat nicht funktioniert.")
        console.log("data", data);
        console.log("status", status);
        console.log("header", header);
    })
```

And the Server routes to a file using busboy to save it:

```
uploadFile: function(req,res) {
    console.log("req",req.files);
    if (process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR!= undefined) {
        var cPath = process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR;
    } else {
        var cPath = path.resolve('..', 'data');
    }
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    req.pipe(busboy);
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        var wPath = cPath + '/uploads/documents';
        file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(wPath + '/' + filename));

        file.on('end', function() {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
        });
    });
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
        console.log('Done parsing form!');
    });
    res.status(200).end();

}
```

On Localhost everything is working just fine and the data is saved to the server. but i get the response of bad gateway and this header:

```
<title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Gateway</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.<br />
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the issue. I post it so that someone who has the problem can solve it to.

The Web load balancer at openshift is HAproxy and has issues with the upload because the response of the server wasn't identical with the request because of the content type. I switched from $http from angular to an XHR. That solved the issue and works fine. The content-type i didn't set at all. now it works fine.